# Laravel Route - Check if ID does not exist and show 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I don't want to show the page if the ID does not exist.

How can I check this in my web.php routes in Laravel?

I currently have the following route:

```
Route::get('/public/{project_id}', 'ProjectController@public');
```

How can I do a conditional check to see if project_id exists?

I saw there was an option for [Route::bind](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing) in the routing docs -- is that a solution? Thanks

Update Note: Slightly different than the Laravel 4 approach as binding seems to have been baked in to the route class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to use is called [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding). Laravel does what you want out of the box. If the ID is not in the database, it shows a 404 page. However, you need to change your route:

Assuming your Model is called `Project`, the route should look like this:

```
Route::get('/public/{project}', 'ProjectController@public');
```

And your `ProjectController` should look like this:

```
public function public(Project $project) {
```

This way Laravel automatically resolves the project with the ID you provide and injects it into the `$project` variable. If no record with the ID exists, laravel redirects to 404

Comment: This is great. It means I can also clean my code in my controller by not using Request $request and just use the Project model straight away. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But why does it have to be this way? I thought the whole Idea of mapping routes to a resource does this automatically? I am facing the same problem and I am using the ```resource()``` function to map routes to my controller functions

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Patrick Schocke's answer.

If you do not want to use Route Model Binding, you can explicitly check in the controller

```
public function public($project_id) {
    $projectExists = Project::where('id', $project_id)->exists();

    abort_unless($projectExists, 404, 'Project not found');

   ...
    }
}
```

Comment: As an alternative you can also use the Laravel `abort` helper function like so `abort(404, 'Project not found')` to remove the need to build and return the response. Or to also remove the conditional statement you might even use `abort_unless($projectExists, 404, 'Project not found')`. You can read about these more in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#miscellaneous).

Comment: @Bogdan Wow. Thank you so much for these tips. I was unaware of these Laravel helper functions.

Comment: Another option (assuming `id` was the model's primary key) would be to use `findOrFail()`. eg. `Project::findOrFail($project_id)`. This automatically returns a 404 if the item is not found.

Answer (score 3):

Just use laravel's `findOrFail()` methode.
This method will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent.

```
public function public ($project_id) {
    $project = Project::findOrFail($project_id);
}
```

source : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `project_id` does not exist then return `404` error by calling `abort()` function.

```
  public function public($project_id) {
        $project_id_exist = Project::where('id', $project_id)->first();
        if(!$project_id_exist){
            return abort(404);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using laravel route model binding functionality

your route will be

```
Route::get('/public/{project}', 'ProjectController@public');
```

your controller will be

```
public function public(Project $project) {
       // Do your work here using $project model
       //  If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response will automatically be generated. 
}
```